# Creating an abstract model to retrieve data

Tags: java, database, abstract-class

I'm trying to build an application in MVC which also has a database. I have multiple models which I'm casting data to from my model classes. As the application progress continues it seems to have alot of duplications. In every function in my models I need to open up a connection, statement and resultset build the query etc. and get the data with the `result.next();` statement.

To get rid of these duplications I started on an abstract class called AbstractModel. My goal is to extends all models to this class and pass the query. The hard part for me is where I need to retrieve data in the `result.next()` loop.

I thought that I could pass the resultset back to my model, but then I cant close my resources anymore.

One of my model classes.

```
public class BezoekerModel
{

    public Gebruiker getGebruiker(String username, String password)
    {
        Gebruiker user = null;

        PreparedStatement stat = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        Connection conn = null;

        try
        {
            conn = SimpleDataSourceV2.getConnection();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM gebruiker WHERE gebruikersnaam = ? AND wachtwoord = ?;";
            stat = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stat.setString(1, username);
            stat.setString(2, password);
            result = stat.executeQuery();

            while (result.next())
            {
                String gebruikerstype = result.getString("gebruikerstype");
                String voornaam = result.getString("voornaam");
                String tussenvoegsel = result.getString("tussenvoegsel");
                String achternaam = result.getString("achternaam");
                int schoolcode = result.getInt("schoolcode");

                user = new Gebruiker(voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam, gebruikerstype, schoolcode);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                result.close();
                stat.close();
                conn.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: " + ex.toString());
            }
        }
        return user;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm casting all my retrieved data into the Gebruiker object which I'm also returning later on.

This is the abstract model I'm building for now.

```
public class AbstractModel
{

public List<Object> getData(String query) {
    List<Object> data = new ArrayList();


    Statement stat = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = SimpleDataSourceV2.getConnection();
        stat = conn.createStatement();
        result = stat.executeQuery(query);

        while (result.next()) {
            // ?????
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            result.close();
            stat.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.toString());
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

As I said earlier I want to pass the query which is going to be created in the bezoekerModel to the AbstractModel. I have no idea if this is even possible. It would be greatly appreciated if any of you provide input on this, so I dont have to waste any more time.

Comment: Why don't you use a library? JdbcTemplate from Spring?

Comment: Did you mean `public abstract class AbstractModel`? and `public class BezoekerModel extends AbstractModel`?

Comment: @Buildersrejected Yes, but the ones i showed u havent been gotten that far. It was just to show what my goal was. Those 2 classes are not connected now.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I dont want to use any library for now because it is an school project and I want to do it myself.

Comment: @user3406942 The library is very simple, look at its source code and borrow some ideas.

Comment: Look up something called the Repository Pattern. Regarding "it's a school project, I want to do it myself", okay, that's great and all, but you'll find once you graduate that the majority of companies use libraries to do all the heavy lifting of database transactions for Java objects, so you really could be focusing on writing the other code for your project

Comment: @cricket_007 I might take a look into that. Thanks for the advice ! Furthermore I changed the code to what BuildersRejected suggested earlier and cleaned up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If AbstractModel is the parent and BezoekerModel is the child of AbstractModel, you can create a method in the parent class "AbstractModel" that handles your query and passes the result back to the child class.

```
    public abstract class AbstractModel { 

    //current arraylist code
    PreparedStatement stat;
     ResultSet result;
     Connection conn;
    protected ResultSet processQuery(String query,String username, String password) {

     try { 
            conn = SimpleDataSourceV2.getConnection(); 
            String _query = query;
            stat = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stat.setString(1, username);
            stat.setString(2, password); 
   return result = stat.executeQuery(); 
    }
    } catch (SQLException ex) { 
         //.....
}
}
```

This should handle building your query. Now your BezoekerModel will say this instead:

```
    public class BezoekerModel { 
public Gebruiker getGebruiker(String username, String password) { 
Gebruiker user = null;
ResultSet result = processQuery("SELECT * FROM gebruiker WHERE gebruikersnaam = ? AND wachtwoord = ?;",username,password);
    while (result.next()) { 
    String gebruikerstype = result.getString("gebruikerstype");
    String voornaam = result.getString("voornaam");
    String tussenvoegsel = result.getString("tussenvoegsel");
    String achternaam = result.getString("achternaam"); 
    int schoolcode = result.getInt("schoolcode"); 
    user = new Gebruiker(voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam, gebruikerstype, schoolcode); 
    } 
} catch (SQLException ex) { 
     ex.printStackTrace(); 
} finally { 
     if (result != null || stat != null || conn != null) {
           try {
           result.close(); 
           stat.close(); 
           conn.close();
           }
} catch (SQLException ex) { 
      System.out.println("Error: " + ex.toString());
 }
      } //end of if
 } return user; } }
```

This is much cleaner and should solve any system resource problems you may have.

Comment: It is the same thought I had before but i had no idea how to return the resultsets etc. But when you return the resultset, the conn and the preparedStatement will it cause the system to clog up the system resources?

Comment: I don't think so, BezoekerModel owns all the methods you are calling, in theory you are simply calling a second method from the same class. If you are worried about system resources, you can make the connection, query and resultset as class vars rather than instance vars. In fact, I'll update my answer with this method.